# Does Spark Continuous Processing support Stateful Operations like FlatMapGroupswithState

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

Does Spark Continuous Processing support Stateful Operations like FlatMapGroupswithState getting error like Continuous processing does not support AppendColumns operations.

Answer (score 1):

No. According to [this part](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.3/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#supported-queries) of the documentation "aggregations are not yet supported" in continuous mode, this includes group aggregations.